# Is it an appropriate question for me to ask how you can create animated gif files of molecules in Windows 7?

Tags: discussion

I thought maybe this question may fall under "software recommendation" which I've been informed is off-topic, if this is the case, would this problem be subverted by me modifying the question to:

"How can you create animated gif files of a series of image files in Blender?"

Comment: The only way of answering that question would be a step-by-step tutorial which you could figure out and answer yourself.  Its still not a great question and likely will just go unanswered.

Comment: If you just want to combine a series of pre-rendered images into a .GIF sequence?  You can use GIMP (free) or Photoshop (paid) to do that, given you already know how to export the image sequence from Blender.

Comment: [Utility to quickly convert a sequence of images to an animated GIF](http://superuser.com/questions/115400/utility-to-quickly-convert-a-sequence-of-images-to-an-animated-gif)

Answer (score 1):

Gif creation I don't believe is really on-topic for Super User.  I would suggestion looking at either:

### Graphic Design:

> Graphic Design is for questions targeted toward 2D design
> professionals, students, and enthusiasts.
>
> This includes questions about:
>
> - Graphic arts theory and history; "Why" we do what we do and not necessarily the "how" in logo design, fonts & typography, visual communication
> - Web design
> - Layout and printing
> - Illustration
> - **Digital media**  
>   Examples: video, Adobe Flash

*Note: This site may be more about the "Why" of things, than the actual "How".  For both this and the other site I would review the questions being asked there, and even ask on their meta site if the question is appropriate.*

or

### Audio-Video Production:

> The Audio-Video Production Stack Exchange is for engineers, producers,
> editors, and enthusiasts spanning the fields of audio, video, and
> **media creation.**
>
> If you have a question about
>
> - broadcast, film, audio, music, or location recording techniques
> - editing, mixing, **mastering**, and distribution
> - post-production techniques
> - signal processing in a production context (for highly technical questions about digital signal processing, please visit Stack
>   Exchange's DSP site)
> - asset management, media, and file formats
> - **installation, configuration, and operation of software related to these topics**